# my modal not showing

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

please tell me why my modal in bootstrap 3 not showing

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button>

<div class="fade modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-describedby="loginModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
tes
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my css include in my bootstrap

```css
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this is my js include in my bootstrap

```js
   <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need JQuery for the bootstrap modal  to work. Include jquery before bootstrap.js and you are good to go. PS. bootstrap.min.js is the minified version of bootstrap.js. No need of including it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : Include Jquery , Bootstrap JS & CSS

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

```
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"> Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: i done edit my post and i use js and css like my post, but modal still not showing

Comment: There is no jQuery in your code. Add jQuery above bootstrap JS. I've added those in my code.